# Proof verification for $\dim(U) = \dim(U\cap{W})$ if and only if $U\subset{W}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

As a newbie to proofs, I'm hoping someone can check on my proof below:

> Suppose $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. Prove that $\dim(U) = \dim(U\cap{W})$ if and only if $U\subset{W}$

My attempt:

Proof.

Suppose $\dim(U) = \dim(U\cap{W})$ and $U$ has a basis $\{u_1, ..., u_m\}$. Then,

$$\dim(U) = m = \dim(U\cap{W})$$

$$\implies U = U\cap{W}$$

$$\implies |W| \geq |U|$$

Further, $W$ has at least $m$ linearly independent vectors that are in $U$, and so $U\subset{W}$.

Thus, $\dim(U) = \dim(U\cap{W}) \implies U\subset{W}$.

Now suppose $U\subset{W}$ and $\{v_1, ..., v_m\}$ is a basis for $U\cap{W}$

From the definition of subsets, $U = U\cap{W}$

So, $\{v_1, ..., v_m\}$ is also a basis for $U$, and so, $\dim(U) = \dim(U\cap{W})$

Thus, $U\subset{W} \implies \dim(U) = \dim(U\cap{W})$.

QED.

This proof seems fairly too simplistic and I feel like I'm missing some important parts. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: \dim instead of dim, please

Comment: In the first part, you went straight from $\dim(U)=\dim(U\cap W)$ to $U=U\cap W$, which is essentially what you are trying to prove.

Comment: $U \subset W \implies U \cap W =U$ then you can directly say $\dim (U) = \dim(U \cap W)$

Comment: Instead of taking basis for $U$, you should take a basis for $U \cap W$ then argue that this basis also span $U$, thus they must be equal, thus $U \subset W$.

Comment: @ElliotG I said that because it follows from some theorem that suggests if $\dim(W) = \dim(V)$ then $W = V$ for vector spaces, $W$ and $V$

Comment: @PNDas Wouldn't it be wise to show that they have the same basis and therefore the same dimension? After all, in my experience, the definition of dimension follows from bases (for your first comment).

Comment: @TRONIX That is clearly false; any line in the plane has dimension $1$, but not all lines are the same.

Comment: @Servaes https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1716411/given-that-w-is-a-subspace-of-v-prove-dim-w-dim-v-implies-w-v

Comment: Yes; *"Given that $W$ is a subspace of $V$...."*. which is precisely what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @Servaes Yeah, I see your point. But doesn't the definition of sets imply that the intersection of two sets is a subset of each of those sets? And the intersection is a subspace too, so shouldn't that imply the theorem?

Comment: You need to justify why $dim(U\cap W)=dim(U)$ implies $U\cap W=U$. So suppose $U\cap W$ is a proper subspace of $U$, and pick a basis $B$ for $U\cap W$. What does this say about $B\cup\{v\}$ where $v\in U\setminus W$?

Comment: @halrankard2 $B\cup\{v\}$ is linearly dependent since $v$ can be written as a linear combination of vectors in $B$?

Comment: Why would $v$ be a linear combination of vectors in $B$? [[Notice that I'm trying to guide you through the proof of the *contrapositive* of what you need to show, i.e., if $U\cap W$ is a proper subspace of $U$ then $dim(U\cap W)<dim(U)$.]]

Comment: I presume because all vectors in $B$ are also in $U$, from the fundamental idea of intersections. Further, since both have the same dimension, they also have the same number of linearly independent vectors. So, vector $v$ must be a linear combination of vectors in $B$ (since $B$ is also a basis for $U$)?

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, where you prove that $\dim(U)=\dim(U\cap W)$ implies $U\subset W$:

1. The conclusion that $U=U\cap W$ comes out of the blue, without any justification.
2. The conclusion that $|W|>|U|$ again lacks justification. In fact it is false and irrelevant.
3. You have chosen a basis for $U$, but haven't used this at any point. So why mention it?

For the second part, where you prove that $U\subset W$ implies $\dim(U)=\dim(U\cap W)$:

1. Again you choose a basis, but don't use it at any point.

You say the proof seems overly simplistic. But to me it seems overly complicated. Instead prove:

**Proposition:** If $U$ and $V$ are vector spaces and $U\subseteq V$, then $\dim(U)\leq\dim(V)$.

Now you simply need to use the fact that $U\cap W\subseteq U$, with equality if and only if $U\subset W$.

Comment: The main question boils down to:  "'If $U\subseteq V$ and $dim(U)=dim(V)$ then $U=V$." How does your Proposition help with this?